# Formula Changes When Rows Cleared

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula set up as below to see which last row number which contains data on another worksheet -

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX((CSV!$A$5:$A$235<>"")*ROW(CSV!$A$5:$A$235)))
```

However, when I clear the contents of the range, and then add anything else in the formula changes from $A$5 to $A$12, or wherever the previously cleared cells would have ended, thus making the max number as 0. How can I fix this please as it needs to be from A5 every time?

Comment: The formula changes if you insert-delete rows on the target sheet. You say "clean" the contents, but you also do something else...

Comment: If you don't want the range to be impacted if you **insert** or **delete** any of the referenced cells, you could use INDEX like this: `INDEX(CSV!$A:$A,5,):INDEX(CSV!$A:$A,235,)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try: `=LOOKUP(2,1/(CSV!A5:A235<>""),ROW(CSV!A5:A235))`